# Connect 4 game exception handler for array In Java

Tags: java

I already finished my program it is a connect 4 console game the only problem is I don't know where should I place my ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in the code in order for it to this is what I want to put in the code

```
try {
     int element = Input.nextInt();
     System.out.println("Element in the given index is :: "+myArray[element]);
  } catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
     System.out.println("The index you have entered is invalid");
     System.out.println("Please enter an index number between 0 and 6");
  }
```

this is the game code it is made out of 3 classes
I'll post the game Engine for the program if it is not helpful I'll post the gameboard

```
public class C4GameEngine {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String Start = "+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+\n" +
            "| Welcome to Connect Four console application. |\n" +
            "| Each player alternately drops a 'R' or 'Y' into one of the seven columns. |\n" +
            "| The objective of the game is to connect four of the same characters in |\n" +
            "| a row, column or diagonal. |\n" +
            "+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+ ";
    System.out.println(Start);
    //We will use the scanner for using input have Input as reference variable
    Scanner Input = new Scanner(System.in);
    //making the red player enter their name
    System.out.println("Red player enter your name: ");

    String red = Input.nextLine();
    //calling out the player class
    PlayerClass p1 = new PlayerClass(red, "R");
    //yellow player to enter their name
    System.out.println("Yellow player enter your name: ");

    String yellow = Input.nextLine();
    //calling the player class for the yellow player
    PlayerClass p2 = new PlayerClass(yellow, "Y");
    // creating the while loop the purpose of it is to make the player decide if they want to keep playing
    while (true) {
        System.out.print("Do you want to keep playing? Type Y or N: ");
        if (Input.nextLine().equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
            //making the board game pattern and calling the connect four board
            String[][] board = C4Board.createPattern();
            boolean loop = true;
            //in order to keep track of the turns
            int count = 0;
            C4Board.drawPattern(board);

            while (loop) {
                //this will let the red have the first turn then after every other turn yellow will play
                if (count % 2 == 0) C4Board.dropRedPattern(board, p1.getName()); //getting the name
                else C4Board.dropYellowPattern(board, p2.getName());
                count++;  //keeping track of the turns
                C4Board.drawPattern(board);
                if (C4Board.checkWinner(board) != null) {
                    //using the if statment to print out the winner if it is red
                    //one point will be set to red and then the question will repeat
                    //do you want to keep playing if you say Y you'll go back to the
                    //new game until you go with N it'll get out of the loop and show you the stats
                    if (C4Board.checkWinner(board) == "R") {
                        System.out.println("Red won.");
                        p1.setGameWon();
                    } else if (C4Board.checkWinner(board) == "Y") {
                        System.out.println("Yellow won.");
                        p2.setGameWon();
                    }
                    loop = false;
                }
            }
        } else if (Input.nextLine().equalsIgnoreCase("N")) {
            System.out.println(p1.toString());
            System.out.println("--------------------");
            System.out.println(p2.toString());
            System.exit(0);


        }
```

And now the gameboard

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

//Creating the connect four board body

public class C4Board {

```
//We need to first create the basic visual pattern first using 2D array
public static String[][] createPattern() {
//creating a double array named field that will hold the length of array
    String[][] field = new String[7][15];
    // creating a loop for each row
    for (int i =0;i<field.length;i++) {
        // creating a loop for each column
        for (int j =0;j<field[i].length;j++) {
            if (j% 2 == 0){
                //the column will be either empty or have a | depending on the disk
                field[i][j] ="|";
            } else {
                field[i][j] = " ";
            }
            //creating the base for the row
            if (i==6) field[i][j]= "-";
        }

    }
    return field;
   public static void drawPattern(String[][] f) {
    for (int i =0;i<f.length;i++) {
        for (int j=0;j<f[i].length;j++) {
            System.out.print(f[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}

public static void dropRedPattern(String[][] f, String Name) {
    //the first move would be is to have the User to tell us
    //where he wants to drop the disk which column
    System.out.println("+----------------------------------+\n");
    //the Name String will display the end name of the user in game stat
    System.out.print(Name + " drop a red disk at column (0–6):\n ");
    System.out.println("+----------------------------------+\n");
    //using it for keyboard input
    Scanner Input = new Scanner (System.in);

    int c = 2*Input.nextInt()+1;
    for (int i =5;i>=0;i--) {
        if (f[i][c] == " ") {
            f[i][c] = "R";
            break;
        }
    }
}
//this is the same as for the yellow disk
public static void dropYellowPattern(String[][] f, String Name) {
    System.out.println("+----------------------------------+\n");
    System.out.print(Name + " drop a Yellow disk at column (0–6):\n ");
    System.out.println("+----------------------------------+\n");

    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
    int c = 2*scan.nextInt()+1;
    for (int i =5;i>=0;i--) {
        if (f[i][c] == " ") {
            f[i][c] = "Y";
            break;
        }
    }
}

//for the check winner in connect four you can win in many ways
//so there is going to be a for loop checking each of those
public static String checkWinner(String[][] f) {
    //checking horizontal line
    for (int i =0;i<6;i++) {

        //the red or yellow disk or nothing will be in odd places
        //we'll start from 0 (which will be 1) and stop at 6 (which will be 7)
        for (int j=0;j<7;j+=2) {
            if ((f[i][j+1] != " ")
                    && (f[i][j+3] != " ")
                    && (f[i][j+5] != " ")
                    && (f[i][j+7] != " ")
                    && ((f[i][j+1] == f[i][j+3])
                    && (f[i][j+3] == f[i][j+5])
                    && (f[i][j+5] == f[i][j+7])))
              //returning the color if the pattern is the same
                return f[i][j+1];
        }
    }
    //vertical line looping over each odd column to check for repeated boxes in the same column
    for (int i=1;i<15;i+=2) {
        //we are vertically checking each line of the code now by the for loop statement so it's from 0 to 2
        for (int j =0;j<3;j++) {
            if((f[j][i] != " ")
                    && (f[j+1][i] != " ")
                    && (f[j+2][i] != " ")
                    && (f[j+3][i] != " ")
                    && ((f[j][i] == f[j+1][i])
                    && (f[j+1][i] == f[j+2][i])
                    && (f[j+2][i] == f[j+3][i])))
                return f[j][i];
        }
    }
    //For the diagonal line the loop has to go over the 3 uppermost rows
    //then left to right column

    for (int i=0;i<3;i++) {

        for (int j=1;j<9;j+=2) {
            //still using the odd index for the column and incrementing by 2
            if((f[i][j] != " ")
                    && (f[i+1][j+2] != " ")
                    && (f[i+2][j+4] != " ")
                    && (f[i+3][j+6] != " ")
                    && ((f[i][j] == f[i+1][j+2])
                    && (f[i+1][j+2] == f[i+2][j+4])
                    && (f[i+2][j+4] == f[i+3][j+6])))
                return f[i][j];
        }
    }
    //this is the same as above but instead of going left to right we will go the opposing direction
    for (int i=0;i<3;i++) {
        for (int j=7;j<15;j+=2) {
            if((f[i][j] != " ")
                    && (f[i+1][j-2] != " ")
                    && (f[i+2][j-4] != " ")
                    && (f[i+3][j-6] != " ")
                    && ((f[i][j] == f[i+1][j-2])
                    && (f[i+1][j-2] == f[i+2][j-4])
                    && (f[i+2][j-4] == f[i+3][j-6])))
                return f[i][j];
        }
    }
    //the null statement will return nothing if it doesn't find any disk anywhere
    return null;
    
}
```

}

Comment: Rather than using an exception in this manner, I recommend that you simply validate the input and prompt the user to enter different values if they enter incorrect values.

Comment: for me, an exception handler is needed this is like a class project I did most of it right but I didn't use exception handlers before

Comment: If using exceptions is a mandatory requirement, you might want to state that in the question.